# Validating using the Model before Querying DB

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I can do this to search the Table for emails.

```
// controller method
public function forgot_password() {
    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
    } else {
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            $user = $this->User->findByEmail($this->request->data('User.email'));
            if ($user) {
                    $this->request->data['User']['id'] = $user['User']['id'];
                    $this->request->data['User']['random_string'] = $this->String->random();
                    unset($this->request->data['User']['email']);
                    $this->User->save($this->request->data);
                    // $this->_sendEmail($user);
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Instructions has been sent to your email'), 'flash');
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'forgot_password'));

            } else {
                // passed! do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}


// validate in the model
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'An Email is required'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'Email is invalid'
        ),
        'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => array('isUnique'),
            'message' => 'Email is already in use'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A password is required'
        )
    ),
    'role' => array(
        'valid' => array(
            'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
            'allowEmpty' => false
        )
    )
);
```

The above code works fine.

I was just thinking to validate if the email is a valid email or empty before even querying the database. I came up with the one below. The problem I have is that setting User with `$this->request->data`. Whenever I validate, it runs through the isUnique rule and fails.

```
public function forgot_password() {
    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
    } else {
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            $this->User->set($this->request->data);
            if ($this->User->validates()) {
                $user = $this->User->findByEmail($this->request->data('User.email'));
                if ($user) {
                    $this->request->data['User']['id'] = $user['User']['id'];
                    $this->request->data['User']['random_string'] = $this->String->random();
                    unset($this->request->data['User']['email']);
                    $this->User->save($this->request->data);
                    // $this->_sendEmail($user);
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Instructions has been sent to your email'), 'flash');
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'forgot_password'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has someone done a solution similar to what I want?

Comment: Would help if you wrote a brief explanation (as opposed to just the code) of what you've done / hope to do.

Comment: I think I explained a lot already up there. I validated and it fails because of the validation rule, `isUnique`. I wanted to validated the model without querying the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this from your controller.

```
App::uses('Validation', 'Utility');
if (Validation::email($this->request->data('User.email'))) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is doesn't add to the validation errors

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Dave that you're not quite clear about what you are trying to do.

First your access of the request data should probably be $this->request->data['User']['email']; if you are posting data in the standard form helper format.

I'm pretty sure that model validation would fail before querying the database in your save call if the value is empty or the email rule fails.  Since notEmpty is the first rule, it would be checked by the validation utility prior to querying the database.  If it failed, then the field would be skipped and no db call made (as long as 'last' does not equal false.  Same applied to the email rule since cake uses a regex pattern for that rule.  You can follow the chain of events by reviewing the save function in Model.php.

If not empty and email rules pass, the eventually you would have to query the db to find if the address already exists.

Comment: I can't agree with the clearer part of your answer but I agree with your statements about it not querying yet. Haven't been sleeping :p

Comment: Ok. Can I bypass the validation on `isUnique` on the fly? Since I am getting the error on `isUnique`.

Comment: Yes, there is a section for dynamically changing rules in the cake docs.  But I'm of the opinion your approach is the issue here, not the way cake handle validation. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Comment: I actually got it a while ago. I just unset the validation error using unset($this->User->validate['email']['isUnique']). If you edit your answer and add that I will accept it.

Comment: Your answer isn't how I would approach this problem, nor is it what I think the solution should be. I think that unsetting the value is putting a band-aid on a larger problem, which is your approach to validation. If you want unsetting the value to be the answer to your question, then I would suggest creating your own answer.